# ファイルをアップロードすると自動的に加工結果を生成してDLリンクを表示してくれるウェブサービスの仕組みを教えてください。

Tags: html, webapi

漠然とした内容ですみません。
PDFの軽量化サービスやZIP化サービス、イラスト・画像等の素材アップロード時、ウォーターマーク（透かし）の自動差し込みなど様々なサービスがありますが、どのようなプログラムが動作しているのでしょうか。

選択した画像ファイルに加工を行ってくれるプログラム一式と、コマンドラインのようなプログラムに命令を出すコードの自動生成＞起動という流れをサーバー上で処理しているのでしょうか。

PHPやJavascriptなどの言語の範囲でそのような加工ができるのでしょうか。
APIに引数を渡すと戻り値で結果が帰ってくるような感じでしょうか。

可能であれば、動作に必要な明確な条件があればそれも探しています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: いろいろな方法があると思いますが、一番元になっているのはCGIじゃないでしょうか？https://www.gadgety.net/shin/tips/web/html.html

Answer (score 1):

レンタルサーバなどで、PHPしか使えないような場合を想定されているのでしょうか。

だとしても、PHPライブラリは多岐にわたって用意されているので、一から実装しなくてもライブラリを使うことでかなりの範囲のことができます。

ご質問に書かれているように、時間がかかる処理をexec関数で別プロセスとして起動して、結果だけを後から取得するような方法も可能です。また、exec関数で呼ばれる処理自体もPHPで記述できます(コマンドラインでPHPモジュールを実行させれば良い)。

気を付けないといけないのはレンタルサーバでは、複数のユーザで一つのサーバをシェアして使用していることがありますので、帯域やCPUの処理時間、メモリ等を長時間独占して使用するようなプロセスを見つけると、自動的に強制終了する仕組みが入っている場合が多いので、負荷をかけないように実装しなければいけないということです。

あとは、使用したいライブラリをある程度自由にインストールできるように解放してくれているサーバでないと、サーバ側で用意されていない機能を探してきても使えない、ということがありますので、利用にあたってどういう縛りがあるサーバなのかを良く見極める必要があります。